# true, if given variable is matching all element/column in given array ( Multidimensional ) in php

Tags: php, arrays, variables, multidimensional-array

Array :

```
$my_value_is = Array ( [2] => Array ( [id] => 2 [price] => 23) [50] => Array ( [id] => 50 [price] => 56 ) )
```

$my_var = 56;

I need it to return true if all columns ( price ) match that given variable value; otherwise, it should return false.

hence as per my $my_var, i should get result as false, because id:2 has price:23 which is not matching.

I tried in_array function, but that wont work :

```
$u_in_array = in_array($my_var, array_column($my_value_is , 'price'));
if($u_in_array ) {
    echo 'value is true';
 } else {
    echo 'value is false';
 }
```

but it giving me as value is true , where as i need value is false.

Comment: _"Below is my array :"_ - please do not present example data in the form of such a print_r output - but either as JSON, or the result of a `var_export()`. Then everyone here has code they can work with immediately, instead of having to re-create your array in code form first.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? `in_array` won't check whether **all** values are the same, but whether **any** value matches

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are currently looking to see if any of the values match (in_array), so it doesn't care that some don't match as long as 1 value does.

There are a couple of ways of doing this.

Firstly by just using a foreach over the array and stopping as soon as one doesn't match...

```
$u_in_array = true;
foreach ($my_value_is as $element) {
    if ($element['price'] != $my_var) {
        $u_in_array = false;
        break;
    }
}

if ($u_in_array) {
    echo 'value is true';
} else {
    echo 'value is false';
}
```

which looks longer, but can be simpler to modify if needed.

If you want to use the array_ functions, you can filter the ones matching and then check if the result is empty, if it's empty - all match...

```
$notMatch = array_filter($my_value_is, fn($element) => $element['price'] == $my_var);

if (empty($notMatch)) {
    echo 'value is true';
} else {
    echo 'value is false';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, foreach logic work properly.Just was thinking, in-case i can get updated array again with updated value, if the results is false.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_diff`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) to check if any value is different in the first array than the second.

The `in_array` will only check for first occurrence and will return true immediately if it does.

```
<?php

$u_in_array = array_diff(array_unique(array_column($my_value_is , 'price')), [$my_var]);

if(empty($u_in_array)){
  echo 'value is true';
}else{
  echo 'value is false';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you extracted the price values using `array_column`, you can simply create an array of only unique values from that. If the count of elements that contains is exactly one, and that first element matches your target price - then the check is passed, otherwise not.

```
function check_all_prices($array, $targetPrice) {
  $test = array_unique(array_column($array, 'price'));
  return count($test) === 1 && $test[0] === $targetPrice;    
}

var_dump(check_all_prices($my_value_is, $my_var));
```